# About using callbacks [Not solved]

Tags: ros, callback, actionlib, roscpp, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I made the `actionlib` tutorial and I was trying to make my own a simple action handler, but there is an error when I use `catkin_make`:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:184:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ControlAction*’ to ‘ControlAction&’
make[2]: *** [control/CMakeFiles/control_server.dir/src/control_server.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [control/CMakeFiles/control_server.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The code  of the action handler is:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <actionlib/server/simple_action_server.h>
#include <control/ControlAction.h>

class ControlAction {
  protected:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    actionlib::SimpleActionServer<control::ControlAction> as_;
    std::string action_name_;

  public:
    ControlAction(std::string name):
    as_(nh_, name, boost::bind(&ControlAction::executeCB, this, _1), false),
    action_name_(name)
    {
      as_.start();
    }

   ~ControlAction(void)
   {
   }

   void executeCB(const control::ControlGoal &goal) {
   }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "control");
  ControlAction control(ros::this_node::getName());
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

And i am using the `geometry_msgs/Twist` as data type in the .action file.
I am looking forward to use this callback to move the turtlebot, how can i use the `cmd_vel` here? (if this were a publisher node_pub.publisher(goal) will be the answer, but there must be another way)

The compilation problem was solved, but stills remaining the other part of the question related about how to use `cmd_vel`
Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202808/about-using-callbacks-%5Bnot-solved%5D/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your callback signature is wrong. It wants a pointer, not a reference, so just add add Ptr to the data type.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-10**:
I changed it to    `void executeCB(const control::ControlGoalPtr &goal)` but still getting

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:184:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ControlAction*’ to ‘ControlAction&’
```

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-10**:
void executeCB(const control::ControlGoalConstPtr &goal)
adding Const and Ptr to the signature of the callback solved the problem!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-02-11**:
@pexison please accept the answer using the checkbox at the left so it's known to be solved.

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-12**:
this was only one part of the question, it remains:

The compilation problem was solved, but stills remaining the other part of the question related about how to use cmd_vel as a callback

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-12**:
It is as you said in the question: You need a publisher to a topic like /cmd_vel that continuously publishes the Twist the robot should execute. There usually is no other way as that is what the robot interface provides.

**Comment by [saurabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28038/saurabh/) on 2018-06-14**:
Hello @dornhege, I am facing similar compilation issue, but I used pointer only. Still it is there.
Can you please have a look on it:
https://answers.ros.org/question/294052/compilation-error-in-ros-action-server-code/